# build and push docker images with GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to build and push docker images to my local nexus repo with GitLab CI

This is my current CI file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u some_user -p nexus-rfit some_host

stages:
  - build

build-deploy-ubuntu-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t some_host/dev-image:ubuntu ./ubuntu/
    - docker push some_host/dev-image:ubuntu
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

I also have a job for an alpine docker image, but when I want to run any of it it's failing with the following error:

```
Checking out 13102ac4 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So technically the docker daemon in the image isn't running, but  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitLab folks have a reference on their docs about using docker-build inside docker-based jobs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor. Since you seem to have everything in place (i.e. the right image for the job and the additional `docker:dind` service), it's most likely a runner-config issue.

If you look at the second step in the docs:

> 2. Register GitLab Runner from the command line to use docker and privileged mode:
>
>    [...]
>
>    **Notice that it's using the privileged mode to start the build and service containers.** If you want to use docker-in-docker mode, you always have to use `privileged = true` in your Docker containers.

Probably you're using a runner that **was not configured in privileged mode** and hence can't properly run the docker daemon inside. You can directly edit the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` on your registered runner to add that option.

(Also, read on the section on the docs for some more info about the performance related to the storage driver you choose/your runner supports when using dind)